# Can you restore a DynamoDB table using point in time recovery if it the table is deleted?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have enabled the point in time recovery on my DynamoDB table. Will it be possible to restore my table if the table itself is accidentally deleted?

It seems point in time recovery only protects against the deletion of the table items rather than the table itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/PointInTimeRecovery_Howitworks.html), an accidentally deleted table can still be recovered with point in time recovery enabled.

> *When you delete a table that has point-in-time recovery enabled, DynamoDB automatically creates a backup snapshot called a system backup and retains it for 35 days (at no additional cost). You can use the system backup to restore the deleted table to the state it was in just before deletion. All system backups follow a standard naming convention of table-name$DeletedTableBackup.*

Comment: It seems the link above is no longer valid, I cannot find the quoted statements in the document pointed out by the link.

Comment: The answer still applies. Check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/PointInTimeRecovery_Howitworks.html#howitworks_deleting